# Conectar colunas de diferentes tabelas

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID AS 'ID' 
    ,e.FIRST_NAME + ',' + e.LAST_NAME AS 'Name'
    ,(SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS WHERE HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENT_ID) AS 'Department Name'
    ,e.SALARY AS 'Base Salary'
FROM [HR].[EMPLOYEES] e
WHERE e.COMMISSION_PCT IS NOT NULL AND e.SALARY IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID AS 'ID' 
    ,e.FIRST_NAME + ',' + e.LAST_NAME AS 'Name' 
    ,(SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS WHERE HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENT_ID) AS 'Department Name'
    ,e.SALARY AS 'Base Salary'
FROM [HR].[EMPLOYEES] e
WHERE e.COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL AND e.SALARY IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY e.SALARY DESC;
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID AS 'ID' 
    ,e.FIRST_NAME + ',' + e.LAST_NAME AS 'Name'
,(SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS d WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID) AS 'Department Name'
,(SELECT JOB_ID FROM HR.JOBS k WHERE e.JOB_ID = k.JOB_ID) AS 'Job ID'
,MAX(e.SALARY)AS 'Base Salary'
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES e
WHERE e.SALARY IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.SALARY
ORDER BY e.SALARY DESC
```

Quando tento ir buscar o nome do departamento que se encontra em HR.DEPARTMENTS, e tento fazer corresponder o DEPARTMENT_ID das duas tabelas, dá-me o seguinte erro:

> The multi-part identifier "HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID" could not be bound.

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID AS 'ID' 
    ,e.FIRST_NAME + ',' + e.LAST_NAME AS 'Name'
    ,(SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS d WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID) AS 'Department Name'
    ,e.SALARY AS 'Base Salary'
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES e
WHERE e.COMMISSION_PCT IS NOT NULL AND e.SALARY IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID AS 'ID' 
    ,e.FIRST_NAME + ',' + e.LAST_NAME AS 'Name' 
    ,(SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS d WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID) AS 'Department Name'
    ,e.SALARY AS 'Base Salary'
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES e
WHERE e.COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL AND e.SALARY IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY e.SALARY DESC;
```

Assim você chama a mesma referência para o HR.EMPLOYEES, que chamou de "e" no "FROM", colocando também um identificador para DEPARTMENTS.

Além disso, retira os colchetes de identificadores das chamadas:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017

Agora uma dúvida, tem certeza que precisa fazer um union pra essa query?

Você não está fazendo a mesma busca duas vezes?

**UPDATE**

Para melhorar a query, tente assim:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID AS 'ID' 
    ,e.FIRST_NAME + ',' + e.LAST_NAME AS 'Name'
    ,(SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS d WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID) AS 'Department Name'
    ,e.SALARY AS 'Base Salary'
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES e
WHERE e.SALARY IS NOT NULL
```

Assim ele vai trazer como você disse que quer no seu comentário, nulos ou não nulos. Tanto faz. Depois você faz o ORDER BY como quiser.

Comment: Funcionou! Sim preciso do union, para correr o query quando a comissão é não nula e quando é nula.Pode só explicar para que serve o  'd' e o 'e'? Sou novo no Sql e ainda não estão bem sólidos esses conceitos

Comment: @BrunoBacelar entendi. Tente então, ao invés do UNION, retirar a cláusula e.COMMISSION_PCT IS NOT NULL na primeira e rodar ela sem o UNION da query debaixo, vou colocar na resposta como deve fazer.

Comment: Ela funciona sem o UNION só que assim vou ter duas tabelas de resultados diferentes e eu quero tudo só numa

Comment: Coloquei na resposta como você deve fazer pra funcionar do jeito que você disse ai. Vê se te ajuda ;) @BrunoBacelar

Comment: Não queria abusar da sua paciência mas preciso de ajuda em mais umas coisas, quero só ver quem tem o maior salário, dei update no código, só que me dá um erro

Comment: @BrunoBacelar Adiciona no final: ORDER BY e.SALARY DESC; que vai funcionar. =)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84751/discussion-between-bruno-bacelar-and-nathalia-delavi).